# Audit Trail Item List 2 BusComp not showing Associate or Disassociate Operations. ver 8.0 +

Tags: audit-trail, siebel, operation, associate

**Our implementation**:
We have added Auditing using the Audit Trail functionality, to a Bus Comp to monitor a M:M relationship between itself and a child (with the use of an intersection table.) as per book shelfs --> Specifying Parent–Child Associations for
Audit section in Siebel Applications Administrator Guide.

**Viewing the Audit Trail**: 
1) Using the Audit Trail Screen -> I can find Associate/Disassociate records. 
2) Using the Audit Trail Item List 2 Bus Comp to have an Audit Trail Tab for a certain view using the section -> Linking Audit Trail to a Business Component section in Siebel Applications Administrator Guide. And here is **The Problem**
It does not display  Associate/Disassociate Operation records even though it is clearly being recorded and we are able to view it in Audit Trail Screen.

With Audit Trail Item List 2 being a VBC, I'm unable to see the logic of where or why it is not showing these operations?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symptoms

Customer added the association of positions to opportunity for Audit Trail by navigating to:

Audit Trail
Select Opportunity
In the Child BC add the Opportunity/Position link

Navigate to the Opportunity view, create an Opportunity and change a user in the sales team field.

In the Audit Trail there are a number of records for Opportunity BCincluding the association and disassociation of positions and the Opportunity history.

However, in the Opportunity > Audit Trail, the audit trail only shows for the Opportunities, not the position change within the opportunity.
Cause

The issue is caused by the search specification in the Opportunity/Audit Trail 2 link
Solution
In Siebel Tools, navigate to the 'Link' object (if this is hidden you will need to show it by selecting the checkbox in View > Option > Object Explorer)

Query for the link "Opportunity/Audit trial Item2"

In the search specification, remove the standard text so this field is empty.

Re-compile the srf and re-start the server.

All records show after this change.